# how to internally resolve short name to FQDN?

Tags: proxy, svn

I am using SVN 1.13.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I need to access the SVN servers through a company gateway.

I've added an http-proxy-host=proxy.mycompany.com (and related port) to /etc/subversion/servers. This works fine if I do an `svn co http://mysvn.mycompany.com/somerepo/trunk mycode`.

But, if I reference my SVN repo by short name, e.g. `svn co http://mysvn/somerepo/trunk mycode`, I am blocked by our gateway. My IT department believes the gateway is functioning as designed. This is a gateway block, not a DNS block - the IP address resolves correctly in either case. It's simply a matter of mysvn not matching the whitelist mysvn.mycompany.com.

Is it possible in Ubuntu to automatically resolve mysvn to mysvn.mycompany.com *before* the URL is sent to the gateway?

Comment: It is the `svn` command that sends the URL to the gateway, so if such "expansion" of the short name (not resolving, because as you said, the name resolves correctly) would be possible, it would have to be done within the `svn` application. I don't know of such a feature.

Comment: "I am blocked by our gateway. My IT department believes the gateway is functioning as designed" Prove your 1st claim and inform the IT department. One of you is wrong. If it is them they need to fix this for you. If not ... your question and the idea you have about is incorrect :)

Comment: @Rinzwind - I have. I don't believe either of us is "wrong". I've seen the gateway ruleset and I understand why the gateway is configured this way. I'm looking for a way to work within the constraints of the environment I have.